# Scrapy - Custom spider, zero crawled despite successful crawler start

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

School assignment

wrote custom spider to extract multiple items from a page - the idea is to pull Job role, company, and location from

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab

tried to follow https://www.accordbox.com/blog/scrapy-tutorial-10-how-build-real-spider/ to create a spider for a different site

this is the code I am working with. Really not sure anymore where to make changes

```
class JobDetail(Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()
  company = scrapy.Field()
  location = scrapy.Field()

class JobItems(Spider):
  name = 'JobItems'
  allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
  start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs']

def parse(self, response):
        yield Request('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs', callback=self.parse_details)

def parse_details(self, response):
  jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="-job-summary"]')
  for job in jobs:
    job = JobDetail()
    job['title'] = job.xpath('.//*[@class="s-link s-link__visited"]').extract()
    job['company'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[1]/text()').extract()
    job['location'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[2]/text()').extract()

    yield jobs
```

nothing comes back with the code above

```
class JobDetail(Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()
  company = scrapy.Field()
  location = scrapy.Field()

class JobItems(Spider):
  name = 'JobItems'
  allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
  start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs']

def parse(self, response):
        yield Request('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs', callback=self.parse_details)

process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 \
                        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'})

def parse_details(self, response):
  jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="-job-summary"]')
  for job in jobs:
    job = JobDetail()
    job['title'] = job.xpath('.//*[@class="s-link s-link__visited"]').extract()
    job['company'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[1]/text()').extract()
    job['location'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[2]/text()').extract()

    yield jobs

process.crawl(JobItems)
```

Zero crawled items with the code above

```
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.6.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.1, Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) - [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Linux-4.14.79+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 \\\n                        (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'}
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: dc701a1b667b9026
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-07-06 20:47:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6028
<Deferred at 0x7f595e7570f0>
```

changes based on suggestion from @abdusco - same output

```
class JobDetail(Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()
  company = scrapy.Field()
  location = scrapy.Field()

class JobItems(Spider):
  name = 'JobItems'
  allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
  start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs']

  def parse_details(self, response):
    jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="-job-summary"]')
    for job in jobs:
      job = JobDetail()
      job['title'] = job.xpath('.//*[@class="s-link s-link__visited"]').extract()
      job['company'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[1]/text()').extract()
      job['location'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="fc-black-700 fs-body2 -company"]//span[2]/text()').extract()

      yield jobs

  def parse(self, response):
    yield Request('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs', callback=self.parse_details)

process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}) 
process.crawl(JobItems)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is indented exactly as in your post, then `JobItems` class can't know how to parse the page. Indent the code properly like below.

Also you're `yield`ing `job`, you should `yield job` instead.

```py
class JobItems(Spider):
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        ...

    def parse_details(self, response):
        ...
        for job in jobs:
           ...
           yield job

process = CrawlerProcess(...)
process.crawl(JobItems)
```

**Edit:** 
The problem is you're missing `process.start()` call after `process.crawl(...)`. The crawler doesn't start without it.

Some remarks:

- Use `.get()` instead of `.extract()` to get a single value. extract gives you a list
- Dont overwrite loop variable `job` with an `JobDetail` instance.
- Remember to clean junk/whitespace surrounding the text
- If you don't really have a startup logic, you could remove `start_requests` and use `start_urls` instead. [Docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)

Here's a working version that uses css selectors:

```py
from scrapy import Item, Spider, Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class JobDetail(Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()
  company = scrapy.Field()
  location = scrapy.Field()

class JobItems(Spider):
    name = 'JobItems'
    start_urls = [
        'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for j in response.css('.-job-summary'):
            job = JobDetail()
            job['title'] = j.css('.s-link__visited::text').get().strip(' -\r\n')
            job['company'] = j.css('.-company span::text').get().strip(' -\r\n')
            job['location'] = j.css('.-company span:last-of-type::text').get().strip(' -\r\n')

            yield job

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(JobItems)
    process.start()
```

output:

```
{'company': 'Horizontal Integration',
 'location': 'San Diego, CA',
 'title': 'Software Engineer'}
...
{'company': 'Healthy Back Institute',
 'location': 'Austin, TX',
 'title': 'Senior PHP / Laravel Developer'}
...
```

Comment: that helped for sure but the response is still zero crawled items

Comment: that worked great!!! thank you for the prompt response. I considered using css but did not know how to pull the first span without a class name, so this was double helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below to get the content you wish to grab. Just run the way it is. No change is required:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy


class JobItems(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'JobItems'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs']

    def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.xpath('//div[@class="-job-summary"]'):
            item = {}
            item['title'] = job.xpath('.//h2/a[contains(@class,"s-link__visited")]/text()').get().strip()
            item['company'] = job.xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"-company")]/span/text()').get().strip()
            item['location'] = job.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[contains(@class,"-company")]/span[starts-with(@class,"fc-black-")]/text())').get().strip()
            yield item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    process.crawl(JobItems)
    process.start()
```

Comment: getting the exact same error that I was with my code

Comment: I suppose you did some modifications otherwise there is no reason for this script to encounter that error. Once again, run it exactly the way it is. Thanks.

Comment: you were right. wasn't working in my python notebook but saved the script as a .py file and ran it from terminal - got responses back!